# delete user card from Stripe Android

Tags: java, android, stripe-payments

I am trying to delete card from stripe using this code :

**First Try :**

```
com.stripe.Stripe.apiKey = getString(R.string.stripe_test_secret_key);
com.stripe.model.Token token = com.stripe.model.Token.retrieve(CardId);
String cardId = token.getCard().getId();
customer = Customer.retrieve(payments.appPreference.getStripeCustomerId());
DeletedExternalAccount delete = customer.getSources().retrieve(cardId).delete();
```

**Error :**
I am getting com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: No such source: card_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx; request-id: req_xxxxxxxxxxxx

**Second Try :**

```
com.stripe.Stripe.apiKey = getString(R.string.stripe_test_secret_key);    
com.stripe.model.Token token = com.stripe.model.Token.retrieve(CardId);
DeletedCard delete = token.getCard().delete();
```

**Error :**
com.stripe.exception.APIConnectionException: IOException during API request to Stripe (https://api.stripe.com): null Please check your internet connection and try again. If this problem persists,you should check Stripe's service status at https://twitter.com/stripestatus, or let us know at support@stripe.com.

Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@koopajah is right. Its not secure from mobile side.

It happened because i created Token but did not call api for creating card. 
Token had Card object but it was not assigned to any client. So, I was getting this error.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do any of this in your Android application as those calls require your Secret API key. You should never have the Secret API key in your Android application otherwise an attacker could get his hands on it and then create charges, refunds or transfers on your behalf.

What you need to do here is handle this code server-side. You'll call the Delete Card [API][1] and make sure that you pass the correct customer and card id in your code. In Java, but server-side, you would do:

```
Customer customer = Customer.retrieve("cus_XXXXXXX");
customer.getSources().retrieve("card_YYYYYY").delete();
```

Comment: I know its not safe from mobile side. But i want to know why its not working. I am trying using currect customer id and card id (from token) but i am getting error.

Comment: @SANAT: the card if from the token wouldn't work. You want the card id as stored *on the customer* which you can look up via the API or the dashboard.